# Failed convert from multipartFile to Blob

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to save document to MySQL database.

I have following controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(
            @ModelAttribute("document") @Valid Document document,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            @RequestParam("content") MultipartFile file) {
```

and form:

```
<form th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${document}"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <h4>Nazwa</h4>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
        <td style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}"></td>

        <h4>Opis</h4>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{description}"/>
        <td style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('description')}" th:errors="*{description}"></td>

        <h4>zawartosc</h4>
        <input type="file" th:field="*{content}"/>
        <td style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('content')}" th:errors="*{content}"></td>
```

and I don't have idea how to fix this error:

> Failed to convert property value of type
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile
>   to required type java.sql.Blob for property content; nested exception
>   is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile]
>   to required type [java.sql.Blob] for property content: no matching
>   editors or conversion strategy found

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to use the file variable to persist.

If you are getting the file correctly, set `file.getBytes()` into your blob field and you should be able to persist it.